# Running an update using a button

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a php/mysql system.
I have a table juncfees which has the fields - juncid, matterid, staffid, fee. The fee stores to hourly rate to be charged for a matter.

The matterid refers to a matter table and staffid refers to a staff table but I don’t think that is relevant for what I want to achieve.

Every year the fees will be subject to an annual rise and what I want to be able to do is to have a page that will enable an admin to do this without involving me. In the past I have changed the values using  code such as UPDATE juncfees SET fee=’45’ WHERE staffid=‘5’; This works fine but I would rather others could do it without direct database access.

I was imagining a page where there was a dropdown list of staff to give me the staffid and a box where the new fee could be entered then a button which, once clicked, would update all of the relevant data.

Is this possible and, if so, how do I go about doing it? (Of course, if there’s a better way then I am happy to follow that route.)

Many thanks

Comment: yes, it's possible using php.  you'll want to look up some tutorials for form submission in php, and updating mysql using prepared statements.

Comment: This rather simple in PHP, literally just a couple lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, possible, going about it well that needs you to look up forms, dropdowns and posting data. Just can't hammer the code out for you to copy/paste. If you run into problems let us know. You just need a page with a dropdown for all members of staff, select click go, then that shows the members of staff fee, click another button to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an adapted sample from w3.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE juncfees SET fee='".$_POST['fee']."' WHERE staffid='".$_POST['staffid']."'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Records updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating records: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The HTML is just a simple form:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
StaffID: <input type=text name=staffid><br>
Fee: <input type=text name=fee><br>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

HTML form is just an example, actually any markup or language which can post http data can trigger the PHP code (which is pretty much all of them). So if you want to create a desktop application to do this that would be quite easy as well.

```
using System.Net;

function postData(float fee, int id)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/update.php");

    var postData = "fee="+fee;
        postData += "&staffid="+id;
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

}
```

Keep in mind, this is just the most basic of example and has no protection as far as user access or from SQL injection.

Comment: If this answers your question please accept it as the answer, if it helps please vote it up.

Comment: That's just what I wanted - it works fine. Thank you.